# Python TimeSeries ploting problem with holidays (no rows dates and times)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

[image]I am trying to plot a column of pandas dataframe with datetime index (timeseries). Some dates and times have no rows in dataframe and when I am going to plot it using simple `df['column_name'].plot()`, on the x axis which is datetime, it shows date and times with no rows in the dataframe and connects data before these empty days to date after it.

How should I get rid of these empty rows in plotting?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you ask for. Could you please provide more details? What chart type is it that you try to make? Could you please draw an example image and attach?

Comment: The image is added. for example between 19-22 Mar my dataframe has no rows on dataframe but in the plot, this period is considered. I want to get rid of this period and many others as you can see in the image.

Is it clear now?

Comment: Almost. Do you want the y-axis to have a jump there, or is it fine if there is just a "gap" in the lineplot?

Comment: No, I want to jump these periods in the plot, i.e remove these periods from my plot. Because there is no corresponding row for these periods in my dataframe.

Comment: The simplest way is to make a scatter instead of a line plot. e.g. `df['AB'].plot(figsize=(10,6),linestyle='None',marker='.')`, then there will be no connection between the datapoints. If you want to connect some datapoints, and have a gap between some datapoints, you have to define when to connect and when not to, which is often a bit tricky. Is fine to simply not connect the lines?

Comment: I checked your proposed solution, but actually I would like to do this on the line plot. I am sure there must be a way to do this on the line plot. So, I am still looking to find a solution for the line plot.

Comment: Sure, there are methods, but they require a little more work. :) Is the data evenly spaced, or is it irregular? How do you know that there is a gap in the data?

Comment: The data is for financial market with the resolution of 1 minute. Some days are holidays so there is no data for those days. Yes, I chacked the dataframe for empty days ans there is no data for holidays.

For every minute there is one row in the dataframe. with open, high, low close and volume data.

Answer (score 0):

When making a line plot, the plotting library don't automatically know between what datapoints there should be a line drawn, and between what points, there should be a gap.

The most straightforward way to tell the library this, I think, is to create NaN-rows so that the index reflects what you think it should reflect. I.e. if you think data should be per minute, make sure that the dataframe index is per minute.

The plotting library then understands that where there is NaN-data, no line should be drawn.

Code example:

```py
# generate a dataframe with one column of 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['2020-04-03 12:10:00',23.2],
        ['2020-04-03 12:12:00',23.1],
        ['2020-04-03 12:13:00',14.1], #notice the gap here!
        ['2020-04-03 12:24:00',23.1],
        ['2020-04-03 12:25:00',23.3],
     ],
    columns=['timestamp','value']
)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp) # make sure that the timestamp data is stored as timestamps
```

Then we create reindex the data, which create new nan-rows where neededn.

```py
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(),end=df.index.max(),freq='1min'))
```

Finally plot it!

```
df['value'].plot(figsize=(10,6))
```

The result looks like 
[image]

Comment: The problem is that I want to remove 12:13:00 to 12:18:00 space on the plot. My index is formatted properly and there is no problem in index fromatting. The only problem is to remove the empty spaces on time axis

Comment: I see. I don't know in that case. Would probably try to manipulate a broken axis directly. See here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html but that seems like a lot of work....